# How do I force the runtime linker to use the shared libraries in the executable directory?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

I have a binary that I want to run in another machine, but I'm getting this error message:

```
./program.run: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /home/ubuntu/lamodal/server/linux/./libxml2.so.2)
```

I'm compiling the program with g++ 8.3.0 using the option `-Wl,-rpath='$ORIGIN'`, and in the directory where I've put the program binary I've also put all the shared libraries that I need. To discover which libraries I needed to put in the directory, in the machine I use to build the program I've run ldd ./program and got a list of libraries, which I proceeded to copy to the directory in the machine where I want to run my program.

However, in the target machine (i.e. the machine I want to run the program at), when I run `ldd ./program` I have this output:

```
./program.run: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /home/ubuntu/lamodal/server/linux/./libxml2.so.2)
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff8a1d8000)
        libwebsockets.so.13 => /home/ubuntu/lamodal/server/linux/./libwebsockets.so.13 (0x00007f5b220d8000)
        libxml2.so.2 => /home/ubuntu/lamodal/server/linux/./libxml2.so.2 (0x00007f5b21ebd000)
        libssl.so.1.1 => /home/ubuntu/lamodal/server/linux/./libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007f5b21e29000)
        libcrypto.so.1.1 => /home/ubuntu/lamodal/server/linux/./libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007f5b21b40000)
        libdl.so.2 => /home/ubuntu/lamodal/server/linux/./libdl.so.2 (0x00007f5b220d2000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /home/ubuntu/lamodal/server/linux/./libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f5b2195e000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /home/ubuntu/lamodal/server/linux/./libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f5b220b6000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /home/ubuntu/lamodal/server/linux/./libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f5b22095000)
        libc.so.6 => /home/ubuntu/lamodal/server/linux/./libc.so.6 (0x00007f5b21773000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f5b213d5000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f5b22020000)
```

As you can see, most libraries that are being linked are in the $ORIGIN directory, that is `/home/ubuntu/lamodal/server/linux/`, with exception of `libm.so.6` and `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`. Both of this libraries are in the directory, but it seems that the linker prefer the ones in other directories.

Some extra information about the machines:

Development machine:

- Ubuntu 19.04 x86_64
- Output of `ldd --version`: `ldd (Ubuntu
  GLIBC 2.29-0ubuntu2) 2.29`

Target machine:

- Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS x86_64
- Output of `ldd --version`: `ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.27-3ubuntu1) 2.27`

Is there a way to force the runtime linker to first look at the $ORIGIN before it look anywhere else?

**Edit**
I tried the answer provided by Employed Russian [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847179/multiple-glibc-libraries-on-a-single-host) and my build command now looks like this:

```
g++ -Wl,-rpath='$ORIGIN' \
    -Wl,--dynamic-linker='$ORIGIN/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2' \
    ...
    -o ./path/to/program.run
```

Then I've copied the `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` in the development machine (located at `/lib64`) to the executable directory at the target machine. The `ldd ./program.run` output remains the same. But now when I try to run `./program.run` I get `No such file or directory` error, which according to some is because the runtime linker was not found. Then I tried to modify the build script to use the full path rather than using `$ORIGIN` but this doesn't solve anything.

Comment: You can not use `$ORIGIN` in the `--dynamic-linker` path, as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48456169/50617. You *must* use actual path to it. If you  don't know where the program will be installed, your only other option is to use explicit loader invocation (see point 3 in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54840445/50617).

Comment: Your approach simply won't work: you are compiling code with a newer GCC on and link it against shared libraries on a newer OS than the the target machine. Libraries that use ELF symbol versioning, like OS `libc.so` and GCC `libstdc++.so`, are only upward compatible. I.e. if a binary was compiled with an older GCC (`libstdc++.so`) and linked against the shared libraries on an older OS (`libc.so`), then it will run on a newer OS but not vice versa. Either switch to an older OS or set up a cross-compiling environment for the lowest-denominator-OS-version on the development machine.